Algorithm Error Bound Induction Proof
The algorithm approximates the value of $\sqrt[]{17}$
Root = 4
for i = 1 to 4 do
   Root = (Root + 17/Root)/2
Return Root

Let Rn be the value of Root after n loops
Let the error bound be En = $\sqrt[]{17} $ - Rn
Using induction prove |En| < (0.5)6(2n) -
3
I am stuck on the inductive step. I've been representing En+1 as $\sqrt[]{17}$ - ($\frac{Rn+\frac{17}{Rn}}{2}$) and working forward from there with no luck. All help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Look up Newton's iteration for square root.
